# Unity 2D Kinematic rigid body goes through dynamic rigid body

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, physics, collision

I am facing a weird 2D physics with Unity issue as demonstrated by the GIF below.

The red objects are kinematic
The green objects are dynamic
The pink wall is static

The red objects have a script that uses `.MovePosition()` to move towards the green object

Why is the red object going through the green object? I am expecting the red object to stop after the green object hits the wall as there is no space to go further. It is even weirder for the circle as the green object jumps to the right of the red object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kinematic rigid bodies act similarly to `Transform.Translate`.

They generally ignore forces applied to them including gravity. However, they can detect collisions with other rigid bodies. For example, in the given scene the red objects will fire up `OnCollision....` functions.

---

In this case scenario kinematic rigid bodies are not suitable but there is a workaround as always.

As `OnCollisionEnter` is still called on collision, you can stop the rigidbody:

```cs
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    // When a collision occurs, stop the Rigidbody's movement.
    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```

Comment: @VishalShah I had the same issue with my game a while ago. It was like a 3D flappy-bird type game. I was at first moving the platform but on encountering this issue, I instead moved the player.